# set a specific formula for a specific column in panda

Tags: pandas, apply

The data frame is like below

df:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |

I want to set a specific formula only for column D.

Formula : (each value in [D] - first value of [D])/SD
SD = df['D'].std()

I wrote this code and did not work:

```
    Funtion = (df.D.iloc[] - df.['D'].iat[0])/SD
    df['D'] = df['D'].apply(Function, axis=1)
```

Is there also a way to use "for" cycle?

Comment: how is `SD` defined?

Comment: @mozway SD = df['D'].std() is the standard deviation

Answer (score 0):

Use simple vectorial code, no need for `apply` (which would be much less efficient):

```
df['D2'] = df['D'].sub(df['D'].iat[0])/df['D'].std()
```

output (as new column D2 for clarity):

```
    A   B   C   D        D2
0   1   2   3   4  0.000000
1   5   6   7   8  0.774597
2   9  10  11  12  1.549193
3  13  14  15  16  2.323790
```

Comment: how we can do the same for each row?

Comment: Use the `axis` parameter of `sub` and `div`